# Joining two tables with same field and merging data into one field (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that I am joining in MySQL using:

```html
select TableA.*, TableB.Reason from TableA
left outer join TableB;
```

My raw tables are like this:

```html
Table A
-----+--------+-------+  
| ID | Contact| Reason|
+----+--------+-------+  
|  1 | Phone  |       |  
|  2 | Mail   |       |
|  3 | Web    |  Info |

Table B
-----+-----------+  
| ID | Reason    |
+----+-----------+ 
|  1 | Complaint |         
|  2 | Info      |       
|  3 |           |
```

And I'm getting this

```html
-----+--------+-----------+---------+  
| ID | Contact| Reason    | Reason  |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+  
|  1 | Phone  |           |Complaint|  
|  2 | Mail   |           | Info    |
|  3 | Web    | Info      |         |
```

But I'm expecting this:

```html
-----+--------+-----------+  
| ID | Contact| Reason    |
+----+--------+-----------+  
|  1 | Phone  | Complaint |  
|  2 | Mail   | Info      |
|  3 | Web    | Info      |
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
select TableA.ID, TableA.Contact, TableB.Reason from TableA
left outer join TableB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

select TableA.ID, TableA.Contact, TableB.Reason from TableA
left join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID ;

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join` condition:

```
select a.id, a.contact, b.Reason
from TableA a left join
     TableB b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Any database other than MySQL requires `on` for `join`.  I'm pretty sure that MySQL requires `on` for `left join`, so I would expect your first query to generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting complete data from Table A thats why you are getting blank reason column also try to select data which you want to show.

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.Contact, TableB.Reason from TableA
left outer join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to correct the relation between tables and joining tables on primary keys is not recommended , you can have unexpected results when the id of one table will not match with the id in second table.

Comment: Hi! What do you recommend? I'm fairly new in MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: you need to place ID in Table b as foreign key in table a  for instance 

instead of Reason in Table A place Reason_ID     as foreign key.
then join both tables TableA.Reason_ID = TableB.ID